# Push to Azure Container Registry is painfully slow at unpredictable times

Tags: azure-container-registry

We're pushing docker images from Azure DevOps pipeline to the repo in ACR.
The build agent is running on a VM in Azure and it's not utilised by anything else.

Sometimes (often at night) the push commands takes 3s, sometimes (mostly during the day UTC) it can take up to 20min.

The tier of our ACR is Standard.

Do you encounter similar problems? Is there to do to avoid these "lags"? 
Since we're pusinh many images per day, this can be really a nuisance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue about this is on Github: https://github.com/Azure/acr/issues/214

For us it has been especially bad yesterday and today.

In the issue on Github they mentioned they are looking into it: https://github.com/Azure/acr/issues/214#issuecomment-509672337

Comment: i have one repo where i pushed with only latest tag, after 2-3 months it was taking more and more time to push, i just deleted that repo from acr repo, and pushed again, seems to work faster now